# Running shell scripts from Mule ESB

Tags: bash, ocr, mule, tesseract

I have a flow set up to recognize when a file is dropped into a directory. Next I need to run a Bash script that processes the file (fairly intensive processing). The script grabs a PDF, creates a temporary directory, breaks the PDF into separate PNG files, runs an OCR processor against each image, converts the result to single-page PDFs, then merges all of the PDFs into a single multi-page PDF with the text layer from the OCR.

The problem is, the Bash script chokes after 10 concurrent transformations are triggered. Right now I have Mule ESB listening for new files, then triggering the script for each file, passing the appropriate parameters. Unfortunately, Mule has two tasks, listen -> trigger. We are going to have over 200 files in that directory that need to be queued for processing, preferably 5 at a time. How do I get Mule to limit the number of concurrent processes triggered?

Below is my initial draft Flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd ">
    <configuration>
    <default-threading-profile doThreading="false"/>
  </configuration>

    <queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy name="limitThreads" maxThreads="2"/>

    <flow name="Poll_DirectoryFlow1" doc:name="Poll_DirectoryFlow1" processingStrategy="limitThreads">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/administrator/Downloads/Input" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" pollingFrequency="5000" fileAge="5000">

        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <property key="originalFilename" value="#[header:originalFilename]"/>
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[def filename = message.getInboundProperty('originalFilename')
                                                        println "$filename"
                                                        def directory = message.getInboundProperty('directory')
                                                        println "$directory"
                                                        "mkdir processed".execute()
                                                        def command = ["/home/administrator/ocr.sh", "$directory/$filename", "/home/administrator/Downloads/Output/$filename"]
                                                        println "$command"
                                                        def proc = "pwd".execute()
                                                        command.execute()
                                                        proc.waitFor()
                                                        println "${proc.in.text}"]]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>        
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here is the actual Bash script (gives some hints on what tools we are using):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setting variables
PARAM=$#
TMPDIR=./split
INFILENAME=${1##*/}
OUTFILENAME=${2##*/}
echo "1 is $1"
echo "2 is $2"
echo "infilename is $INFILENAME"
echo "outfilename is $OUTFILENAME"

#Logging I/O filenames
echo "infile: $1" >> error.log
echo "outfile: $2" >> error.log

#If the temporary directory doesn't exist, make it
if [ ! -d "$TMPDIR" ];
then
    mkdir $TMPDIR
fi

#Check to see that the correct number of params have been passed.
if [[ $PARAM -lt 2 ]];
then
    echo "Usage: $0 source.pdf output.pdf"
    echo "output.pdf is the desired output file"
    echo "source.pdf is a file to be OCR'd"
    exit 1
fi

#Make sure the input file is a PDF
if [ "${1##*.}" == "pdf" ];
then
    multilayer=false

    #Check to see if the input file is a multi-layered pdf with searchable text
        if grep -Fl "Font" "$1"; then multilayer=true; fi

    #If it's not multi-layered, then perform the OCR
    if [ "$multilayer" == "false" ];
    then
        mkdir $TMPDIR/"$INFILENAME/"
        echo "making temporary directory $TMPDIR/$INFILENAME"
        #Split the PDF into pdf's of one page per df in a temporary directory
        pdftk "$1" burst output "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/pg_%04d.pdf"
        echo "burse output to $TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/pg_%04d.pdf"
        mv "$1" processed/
        for files in "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/"*
            do
            echo "$files"
                    filename=$(basename "$files")
                    filename="${filename%.*}"

            #Convert the pdf page into an image
                    gs -r300 -o "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.jpeg" -sDEVICE=jpeg "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.pdf"

            #Perform the OCR against the image
                    tesseract "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.jpeg" "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename" hocr

            #Combine the OCR'd image and OCR'd text into a multi-layer PDF file of that page
                    hocr2pdf -i "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.jpeg" -o "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.pdf" < "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.html"
                    compressed="$filename-compressed.pdf"

            #Compress the multi-layered PDF of the page
                    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$compressed $TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename.pdf"
                    mv "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$compressed" "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/$filename"
            done

        #Concatenate all of the multiline PDF pages into a single PDF file
        pdftk "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME/"*.pdf cat output "$OUTFILENAME"
        compressed="$OUTFILENAME-compressed.pdf"

        #Compress the multi-layered PDF
        gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="$compressed" "$OUTFILENAME"
        mv "$compressed" "$2"
        rm -rf "$TMPDIR/$INFILENAME"
    else
        echo "The input file is multi-layered"
        mv "$1" "$2"
    fi
else
    echo "Please enter a valid input pdf file"
    exit 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@genjosanzo...you put me on the right track thinking about the processing strategy. Here is the solution that ended up working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
    xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd ">

    <queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy
        name="limitThreads" maxThreads="7"
        doc:name="Queued Asynchronous Processing Strategy" />
    <flow name="Poll_DirectoryFlow1" doc:name="Poll_DirectoryFlow1"
        processingStrategy="limitThreads">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/administrator/Downloads/Input"
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" pollingFrequency="60000"
            fileAge="5000">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="^.*\.(pdf)$"
                caseSensitive="false" />
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[def filename = message.getInboundProperty('originalFilename')
                println "$filename"
                def directory = message.getInboundProperty('directory')
                println "$directory"
                "mkdir processed".execute()
                def command = ["/home/administrator/ocr.sh", "$directory/$filename", "/home/administrator/Downloads/Output/$filename"]
                println "$command"
                def cmd = command.execute()
                cmd.waitFor()
                println "$filename has completed processing"]]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Any reason for using Groovy above MEL?

Comment: @DavidDossot How can a shell script be executed using MEL?

Comment: MEL is built on MVEL, from which you can access the whole JDK.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to your problem would be not to use the threading profile based strategy you were setting up and replace the scripting componet with a pooled java component configured like the following:

```
<pooled-component class="org.mule.PooledComponent">
        <pooling-profile exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_WAIT" maxActive="0" maxWait="-1"  initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_NONE"/>
</pooled-component>
```

You should place the invocation of your bash script in that component. You can find the docs about it [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Tuning+Performance#TuningPerformance-AboutPoolingProfiles)